# How to Download the ZIp Folder from Server in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

Hi i want to  download the Zip Folder in iphone application from remote server that have many HTML files and CSS. Then I want to display it on the UIWebview?

Comment: By the way, if you like my answer, you can click the outlined checkmark to accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
NSData *zipFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
```

Then you can use the *–writeToFile:atomically:* method of NSDATA to store the zip file

As far as unzipping it goes, you could try using [ZipKit](http://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home) - I haven't used it yet, but I understand that it is pretty good. I'm about to implement it in the project I'm currently working on myself.

Good luck!